# Working in South Korea. I want to relocate back to California

Tags: job-search, relocation

I currently work at an IT gig in South Korea. Previously, I lived in California. I've worked long enough here to go back to California to find a job there. I've submitted some resumes while living here in South Korea, but I was rejected.

Now I know there was many reasons of why I was rejected, but it made me think, "Is it because I live in South Korea now?"

So my question is, would it be better for me to move back to California AND THEN find a job? Or is it okay for me to stay in South Korea and find a job in California?

Comment: With other things being equal employers always prefer local candidates.

Comment: So telling them "I will relocate back if I get this job" wouldn't suffice?

Comment: Honestly, we can't tell you. Make sure to emphasize that you want to move back any day now. Eventually you'll find something. Good luck!

Comment: Unless you have some very unique qualifications, a local (meaning **already** here) candidate will have inherent advantage.

Comment: Could you not use a California address while applying? Do you have friends that could forward mail to you. Admittedly you would have to pay for flights back for an interview but it may be a step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can afford to be out of work for a while, this may be one case where leaving the old job first -- and moving back -- might help you. As others have said, employers may be nervous about the complexities of interviewing someone currently located half a world away.

Comment: Yep, better if you were back for many reasons. Importantly there is an implication that relocating costs may be involved. But primarily you're not local which quite often gets your application binned just for that.

Comment: *Sigh* I think you're right. It's gunna suck

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't apply cross country I did apply cross state. The main thing people don't want to hear someone planning to move but only with a job. It makes them unsure if you want relocation assistance or what. They rather hire someone who is moving and can work immediately without troubles.

My advice is to make it very clear you plan to move within the month and that you don't need help as far as relocations go.